# Preparing a pull request for a forked github project of a forked github project

Tags: github, git-merge, git-rebase, git-fork

I forked project `B` and made some commits (on master - slap wrists) `C`. `B` was originally forked off `A`, and `B` had submitted a pull request back to `A` which was recently accepted.

The git network looks something like this: (black = `A`, blue = `B`, purple = `C`).

[image: git network]

I want to be able to clean up my repo and commits `C` such that I can prepare to submit clean pull requests back to `A`. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want to have the last PR from `B` in your `C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good case for an `upstream`.

Here is the [walk-thru on Github](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/#step-3-configure-git-to-sync-your-fork-with-the-original-spoon-knife-repository). You'll want to use `A` as the `upstream` repo.

Once you have the `upstream` setup you can merge the `upstream` repo with your fork by following this [walk-thru](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork/), then submit your PR.

Comment: The word ``upstream`` is a useful convention; there is nothing special about the name for a remote repository.